# Dual-Homed Windows Server 2012 Firewall Ports

Tags: windows

I am trying to setup the firewall for a Windows Server 2012 host (domain controller) that also acts as our router.  It has two NICs - an internet-facing one and an intranet-facing one.  Obviously, I want to block a lot of the internet-facing ports without blocking them internally.

The most straightforward way to do this seemed to be to go into Windows Firewall on the server and hit up "Windows Firewall Properties".  Under "Protected Network Connections" I set the Domain and Private profiles to include the intranet but unchecked the internet and on the Public profile I only have the internet NIC checked.

I removed the Public profile from a particular port rule for both TCP and UDP.  All three adapters have "Incoming connections that do not match a rule are blocked".  But, when I check the port using an Internet test utility, the port still shows "open".  What am I missing?

When I troubleshoot via logs I see an entry for the unfamiliar IP address that just shows "ALLOW".  No indications of why it is allowed or what profile was associated.  I tried a server reboot with no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this - especially if you care about security.

- Multi-homing a domain controller is bad practice.
- Running roles other than DNS and AD DS on a domain controller is bad practice.
- Installing additional roles on a server acting as a router is bad practice.
- Exposing a domain controller to the Internet is bad practice.

Install two separate servers to support these vastly different functions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved my own problem, posted here for the benefit of anyone else with my problem.  A detail I omitted was that the port in question was DNS, port 53.  The DNS Server was set to listen on both interface IP addresses.  As such, the DNS Server was calling up the firewall and asking to open that port.  As soon as I constrained the DNS Server to the internal IP Address, the port registers as closed to the internet.  So if anyone else experiences a similar problem, be sure to consider whether any applications might be pushing the port open despite your firewall efforts.